# Javascript The Method Invocation Pattern Sample is not working, why?

Tags: javascript

This snippet is what I found in the book [Javascript - the good parts]

It simply did not work. Missing '}' in the "var myObject..." line as IE8 described an error.

Anything that I missed?

```
// Create myObject. It has a value and an increment
// method. The increment method takes an optional
// parameter. If the argument is not a number, then 1
// is used as the default.

var myObject = {
    value: 0;
    increment: function (inc) {
        this.value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
    }
};

myObject.increment(  );
document.writeln(myObject.value);    // 1

myObject.increment(2);
document.writeln(myObject.value);    // 3
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using IE8 instead of a browser that actually gives you useful dev tools?

Comment: My lack of experience. Good tip.

Comment: Even Firefox 3.6 (which is from Jan 2010) + Firebug is far, _far_ ahead of IE8 when it comes to dev tooling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals), properties are separated by commas (`,`), not semicolons (`;`). Change this:

```
value: 0;
```

to this:

```
value: 0,
```